NiFi: Connecting to Remote Server with GetTCP Processor
I'm new to NiFi and I've been having some issues with the GetTCP processor returning data as a flowfile.
Use case:

There is a remote server  (RS) somewhere that allows TCP connections on specific ports
When a connection is made, a message is returned to the client via TCP connection from the RS

What I am attempting to do is use the GetTCP processor to connect to the RS and have the returned message passed to an additional processor. My understanding is that any message returned to the GetTCP processor is converted into a flowfile and passed to the success flow, however, I never see any message coming back.
I have verified from the command line (using a Python script) that the TCP connection is valid and that I can print the return message to my terminal. I've also captured some of the network packets to ensure I'm getting 20* responses from the NiFi connection attempt, but still nothing in the NiFi processor. Should I be using a different processor for this? Or is there an additional processor (maybe a monitor?) that is needed to actively pull the data being returned into a flowfile?
I've attempted to find answers online, but so far I have found no solutions. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.
UPDATE:
I realized I should have put this in my original question, the data being returned by the remote server is binary data. It has come to my attention that there may be an issue with the GetTCP processor not understanding the end of message delimiter and never closing the stream / sending the flowfile forward. << This is where I believe my issue lies and would be extremely appreciative if there was an alternative to the GetTCP processor for binary data. Otherwise, I imagine I will need to create a custom processor for this task.
